# Powershell scripts are not running

Tags: powershell-2.0

When I launch powershell I get the following message and am unable to run powershell scripts.

```
2013-03-21 14:21:19 [000002fc] info    [native] No Registry-Settings exist for this process
2013-03-21 14:21:19 [000002fc] info    [native] Agent has no active settings - running normally
Windows PowerShell
```

This does not happen on another machine where I have powershell.

Comment: Do any scripts work with powershell?

Comment: Yes. Scripts used to run fine. Not sure what is the recent change causing this. I noticed if I open ps1 file in notepad it shows security warning. In other machine not showing any warning.

Comment: Which security warning do you get? It is a bit fishy, a reinstall of Powershell might be needed.  If it used to work, and suddenly (without change) it stopped on 1 machine, that's not good.  Do other people have the same thing on this machine?   You can try cleaning any profile scripts (machine and user) and then retry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

late reply, but instead of disabling the .net agent, you can suppress initial console logging by adding this env var:

```
DT_DISABLEINITIALLOGGING=true
```

Answer (score 5):

Finally we figured that it was Dynatrace agent hooked in powershell process caused that info/warning. Disabled Dynatrace service, rebooted the server. No more errors.